# Counting the instance of a certain word from the source code

Tags: java, regex

I have a for loop in a Java file, where the code looks like the following (including comments),

```
//This is a for loop 
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {
 System.out.println(i);
}

/*
When you know exactly how many times you want to loop through a block of code, use 
the for loop instead of a while loop
*/
```

I am writing a program to read this file and count the number of "for" loops in the code. The method that does this in my program looks like this,

```
private static int wordCount(String file) throws IOException  {

    String word1 = "for";
    int wordCount = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(file));
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        if (sc.next().equals(word1)){
            wordCount++;
        }
    }

    return wordCount; 
}
```

However, when I run this code, it returns the wordCount as 3 not 1. I believe it does this because it reads strings from the comments sections. How can I modify my code in a way (maybe using regex) to return the wordCount as 1 for this instance?

Comment: Regexes probably won't work in all but the simplest of cases; you really need to use a full-blown parser like [this one](https://javaparser.org/).

Comment: One of the answers raises a good question: What about nested `for` loops?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it should work for nested for loops as well

Comment: In that case, I would recommend just writing a simple parser to count `for` loops.  This would be much safer than trying to use regex, and also would be easier than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

Maybe,

```
(?m)^\\h*\\bfor\\s[\\s\\S]*?^\\h*\\}\\h*$
```

might be somewhat close to figure out an expression for that.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/X8txNz/1/)

> The expression would fail, if there'd be nested `for` loops.

#### Test 1

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){


        final String regex = "(?m)^\\h*\\bfor\\s+[\\s\\S]*?^\\h*\\}\\h*$";
        final String string = "for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {\n"
             + " System.out.println(i);\n"
             + "}\n\n"
             + "for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {\n"
             + " System.out.println(i);\n"
             + "}\n\n"
             + "for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {\n"
             + "    System.out.println(i);\n"
             + "}";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: \n" + matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output 1

```
Full match: 
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {
 System.out.println(i);
}
Full match: 
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {
 System.out.println(i);
}
Full match: 
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

### Method 2

Another method might be to use alternation, collect the undesired `for`s and then desired ones, maybe using an expression similar to:

```
\\/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*\\/|\\bfor\\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/m1zs0c/1/)

#### Test 2

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "\\/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*\\/|\\bfor\\b";
        final String string = "for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {\n"
             + " System.out.println(i);\n"
             + "}\n\n"
             + "/*\n"
             + "When you know exactly how many times you want to loop through a block of code, use \n"
             + "the for loop instead of a while loop\n"
             + "***/\n\n"
             + "for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {\n"
             + " System.out.println(i);\n"
             + "}\n\n"
             + "/****\n"
             + "When you know exactly how many times you want to loop through a block of code, use \n"
             + "the for loop instead of a while loop\n"
             + "*/\n\n"
             + "for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {\n"
             + "    System.out.println(i);\n"
             + "}\n\n"
             + "/*\n"
             + "When you know exactly how many times you want to loop through a block of code, use \n"
             + "the for loop instead of a while loop\n"
             + "*/";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: \n" + matcher.group(0));
        }               

    }
}
```

#### Output 2

```
Full match: for
Full match: /*
When you know exactly how many times you want to loop through a block of code, use 
the for loop instead of a while loop
***/
Full match: for
Full match: /****
When you know exactly how many times you want to loop through a block of code, use 
the for loop instead of a while loop
*/
Full match: for
Full match: /*
When you know exactly how many times you want to loop through a block of code, use 
the for loop instead of a while loop
*/
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/X8txNz/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/X8txNz/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Can you show how this modification could be added to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I would simply write some code to ignore the comments.  Start ignoring when you see a /* and resume parsing when you encounter */.

For // you can see if the index the String "//" in the line is less than the index of "for".  If it is don't count the for.

The reason I would do it this way is that you might encounter something like the following:

```
/*
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {
 System.out.println(i);
}
*/
```

If you read in all the lines of the program as one large string and then process it as such you can do this

```
    // Note: Java 13 text block 
    String program = """
      //This is a for loop 
      for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {
       System.out.println(i);
      }

      /*
      When you know exactly how many times you want to loop through a block of code, use 
      the for loop instead of a while loop
      */
      """;
```

1. The first `replaceAll` removes all /* type comments.
2. The second `replaceAll` removes single line comments to the end of the line
3. The (?s) is a flag indicating permitted multi-line matches.

```
     program = program.replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.*\\*/", "")
                      .replaceAll("^(?s)(.*?)//.*?\n","$1");


    int forCount = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    while ((idx =  program.indexOf("for")) >= 0) {
       forCount++;
       program = program.substring(idx+1);
    }
    System.out.println(forCount + " occurence of for found");
```

Prints

> 1 occurence of for found

Note:  The above works in a pinch but it is not very efficient nor complete.

Consider the following legal syntax.

```
    for 
       (
          int intfor = 10;
          intfor < 20;
          intfor++
          ) {}
```

or

```
String text = "what is the formula?";
```

My method will fail the above.  A nifty regex might solve the problem but
writing a parser to analyze the code on the fly and also permitting all Java keywords to be found would be the way to go and imho, non-trivial.

Comment: What is "program" in this instance? Is it a String?

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica Modifying the file to be read with quotation is not an option. I'm planning on applying this to 1000s of files in a folder

Comment: @coder  You are going to have to write a parser.  You will need to check for `fields`, `class names`, `methods`, `comments`, `interfaces`, `strings`, `enums`, etc to see if they have the word `for` in them.

Comment: Any sample code I could provide would be out of context of the entire solution and of little value.  As I said before, imo, this is a non-trivial exercise.

Comment: It was a quote to show that for can also occur within string literals.